# Selecting specific columns from Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create an array A whose columns are columns in another array B. The problem is that the columns I need are not consecutive, so I can't do something like:

```
A = B[:, 1:4]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Well what are they? Every other column?

Comment: No, there is no pattern. I need columns 1-3, then 5. But I'm thinking that in general there must be a way to concatenate pieces of the array at least.

Comment: See the question in your link